# jquery load dynamic url return whole page instead selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to refresh/reload **a div** with jquery and this code works perfect

```
$("#termlist").load('index.php/?s=1&qact=edit&id=WXU8FFSEBVA8S4AC #termlist');
```

but I'm working with dynamic php URLs so I can't use that code, I can get the Dynamic ID from HTML element like this

```
$("#termlist").load('index.php?s=1&qact=edit&id='+ $("input#id").val() + "#termlist");
```

unfortunately this code refresh the whole HTML/URL instead only a div.
so what i miss ? any ideas ? thanks

Comment: I don't know if it is the point of your question but, in your second line (the line which cause the error), I see you don't put a space bewteen `input#id` and `#termlist`. If you said the code above works, did you try adding a space ?

Comment: @Zeratops haha thanks mate, you are right it's working.maybe I should going to sleep ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that is because your site probably is using some type of routing system.
What you can do is provide the full path to your `load`method like this:

**Localhost:**

```
$("#termlist").load('http://localhost:8888/index.php/?s=1&qact=edit&id=WXU8FFSEBVA8S4AC #termlist');
```

**Server:**

```
$("#termlist").load('http://www.domain.com/index.php/?s=1&qact=edit&id=WXU8FFSEBVA8S4AC #termlist');
```